# Failed to upload *.app

Tags: iphone

I created the App Id in the Apple development program and follow the instructions in apple document.

My App Id is xxxxxxxxxx.com.companyname.appname. In my project's info.plist, i change the bundle identifier from com.yourcompany.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier} to com.companyname.appname. When i tried to run the application in my iphone, i got this error "Failed to upload application_name.app.

Anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you ever found a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citing Apples [Technical Note TN2242](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/technotes/tn2009/tn2242.html):

"The Bundle Identifier (and App ID) is an example of a "Uniform Type Identifier" (UTI), so you can only use valid UTI characters for your Bundle Identifier. In particular, you can't use spaces or underscores."

The UIT character set is described [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_conc/understand_utis_conc.html) on Apples developer site.

Comment: I have this problem, but your solution does not work for me unfortunately. My name only has alpha characters, with no spaces or underscores.

Comment: If your Bundle Identifier only has alpha characters it's not following the recommendations in the Apple Technical Note. Go over the Apple Technical Note and check of the recommendations against your Bundle Identifier.

Answer (score 2):

Build and Upload in Release - active configuration

Comment: Is there a reason release works but debug doesn't? I am having that problem. Strangely, the app does install on the ipad but doesn't run citing the "failed to upload" message.  Release works.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a great solution, because I need to be in Debug configuration to debug the app.